# Is the story arc of "The Twelve" available in collected format?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men

The various X-Men titles had a story arc back around the late 1990's where Apocalypse was kidnapping Omega-level mutants that represented each element. If I remember correctly, he ended up merged with Cyclops at the end and it was also when Wolverine got his adamantium back after Magneto had removed it.

**What was the name of the described story arc, and is it available in a collected edition / trade paperback format?**

Answer (score 1):

I hate to answer my own question, but I found the answer after some additional searching. Turns out the story arc was released in two collected editions titled "[**X-Men vs. Apocalypse**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apocalypse:_The_Twelve)". Both titles are available [on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/X-Men-vs-Apocalypse-Vol-Twelve) as well, although I actually found them elsewhere initially.

[image]